# How can I show exact association rules belong clusters with made by PAM method in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, visualization, apriori, arules

I clustered the association rules with arules package's PAM function in R and this package provides Silhouette Plot of association rules but it just shows the number of rules belong that cluster which is shown below `.png` file but I want to see those rules one by one. For example second cluster has 7 rules and I want to see those rules. Is it possible? Here is the some code that I ran in R:

> library(rio)
>
> library("arules", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
>
> library("cluster", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
>
> data <- import("C:\Users\GokhanGoy\Desktop\Apriori.xlsx")
>
> data2 <- data.frame(sapply(data,as.factor))
>
> install.packages("arulesViz")
>
> library("arulesViz", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
>
> rules3 <- apriori(data2, parameter=list(support=0.5, confidence=0.9))
>
> d <- dissimilarity(rules3,method = "Jaccard")
>
> clustering <- pam(d,k=3)
>
> plot(clustering)

Here is the ".png" file:

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this elegant post that describes in detail how to produce a [minimum working reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) So far its difficult to understand what have you tried? Where is the .png file suggested in the question?.

Answer (score 0):

Use the other attributes of the `clustering` object.

Plotting is not supposed to list the labels, but only the Silhouette.

But based on the Silhouette, the clusters are bad. So why further investigate?